# Jobs scheduling in Google Container Engine (Kubernetes)

Tags: docker, cron, containers, kubernetes, jobs

I'm trying to create a Kubernetes scheduled job, however, I noticed that:

- On Kubernetes versions >= v1.4 it's called *ScheduledJob* 
  (http://janetkuo.github.io/docs/user-guide/scheduled-jobs/)
- On Kubernetes versions >= v1.5 it's called *CronJob
  (http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/cron-jobs/)

The default Kubernetes version running on Google Container Engine is v1.4.6 which means I should use *ScheduledJob* objects.

The problem is that *ScheduledJob* uses the *batch/v2alpha1* API version which isn't enabled on my Cluster so the job creation fails, on the other hand, creating a new cluster with Alpha Features enabled will only last for 30 days (Google automatically deletes it afterward).

Is there any production-ready solution to schedule jobs on Google Container Engine?

Thanks,

Idan

---

**edit:**

Below is the official response from Google Support:

> As you’ve noticed, the scheduled jobs/cron jobs feature is currently
>   in alpha.
>
> We realize this is a much-requested feature and are working to get it
>   production-ready in the future. Until then, there is unfortunately no
>   supported feature I can recommend for production.

Comment: unfortunately, i think you know it all. You can try to trick the system by scheduling regular Pods and setting liveness probe interval to the time you want the job to run; your job Pod would run and die, but be rescheduled after liveness detects a dead pod. Very hacky... ;-)

Comment: Another hack is running `cron` inside a container. Here's an example: https://github.com/aptible/docker-cron-example

Answer (score 1):

There is a milestone to migrate CronJobs to Beta in v 1.8 that can be tracked [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/41039).

Answer (score -2):

The new default version for Google Container as today is [Kubernetes v1.5.6](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes) and you have the option to upgrade to v1.6.0. So it will be possible to create [cron jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/cron-jobs/).

If your cluster is on a previous version, you can upgrade your container cluster as described in [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/upgrade)

Comment: are you sure about that? since from the documentation, it's still in [alpha](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/cron-jobs/#creating-a-cron-job)

Comment: I was referring to the GKE version as today, so you can run now cron jobs, but it is still true that cron jobs will run only if your GKE cluster has enabled Kubernetes alpha features.

Comment: As far as I know, 'alpha features' are available in Alpha Cluster, thus not really production ready.